# My character freezes after touching wall using hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3

I used hittestobject in as3 to stop the player from going through the wall, but I can't move back away from the wall after touching it. how do I make it so the player cannot go through but can back away after pressing the opposite keys?

this is my code:

```
    if (player.collisionArea.hitTestObject(wall))
    {
        player.y -= vy;
    }
```

Comment: With that amount of information, I can only guess what the problem is. I assume `vy` is some kind of velocity. I also assume that you apply this velocity to the coordinates of the player in some kind of update loop. So, think about it. your player runs against the wall, gets set back by the velocity value, then update runs again and the velocity will be added to the player coordinate again. In essence, an endless loop in which the player can't do anything anymore. You could try setting `vy = 0` after `player.y -= vy`

Comment: I set it to 0 when you let go of the key, but if you press down the key, the vy number is 5. And it has this issue, what should I do?